# Ask question about road map of learning technology in SO

Tags: support, stack-overflow, asking-questions, scope

Can I ask questions like "What should I learn? Which resources should I read/study? In what order?" for specific development? I want to ask this on Stack Overflow because it is the most popular site compared to the others in our community.

Comment: What is "learning road map"?

Comment: So you mean to ask something like, *"What should I learn? Which resources should I read/study? In what order?"* ...? If so, then nope, that's not a good fit.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/209252/learning-wdk-development - related.

Comment: Sorry , I had updated the post .

Comment: @Joe.wang: That didn't explain what "learning road map" means.

Comment: @NicolBolas I mean to ask something like, "What should I learn? Which resources should I read/study? In what order?" :)

Comment: @Joe.wang: Then you should *ask about that*, not couch it in random, unknown jargon like "learning road map".

Comment: @NicolBolas Already updated. please review it . If there is something not suitable , please help to edit it . thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Requests for resources, or guidance for your education are off-topic for Stack Overflow. So no, you will not be able to ask such questions there. They will be closed.

The site may be popular, but it has a fairly narrow scope. And the question you propose simply does not fit.